# Should an exact time come before a day when specifying when something will happen?

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

I have a flight tomorrow to leave for France.

- It will leave at 9.45 a.m. tomorrow morning.
- It will leave tomorrow morning at 9.45 a.m.

Which is the correct sentence?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to choose between them so far as correctness is concerned. They are equally idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are 'correct' but typically when there are multiple time adverbs in the same utterance the more specific comes before the less specific.

*At 9.45* is a more specific time than *tomorrow morning* so this typically comes first:

> It will leave at 9.45 a.m. tomorrow morning .

*Collins Cobuild English Grammar* (p266) in the section *ordering of time expressions* states:

> ... the usual order is clock time, followed by the period of the day,
>   day of the week, and date.
>
> - at eight o'clock on the morning of 29 October 1618
> - on the night of Thursday July 16

The alternative word order:

> It will leave tomorrow morning at 9.45 a.m.

is just as grammatical, and may be preferred if '*tomorrow morning*' is the more important information than the clock time.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorrow+morning+at+9%3A45%2Cat+9%3A45+tomorrow+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%20morning%20at%209%3A45%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%209%3A45%20tomorrow%20morning%3B%2Cc0) certainly seem to show that 'at 9:45 tomorrow morning' outperforms 'tomorrow morning at 9:45'. However, the picture is less ...

Comment: clear if one uses [9 o'clock](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorrow+morning+at+9+o%27clock%2Cat+9+o%27clock+tomorrow+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%20morning%20at%209%20o%27clock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%209%20o%27clock%20tomorrow%20morning%3B%2Cc0). Ah, the link doesn't work. Believe me, the Ngrams were there, and intertwined.

Comment: (If you say "a.m.", it is a bit redundant to also say "morning." I would probably leave out one or the other.)

Comment: I also would drop the a.m. part and go with "it will leave at 9:45 tomorrow morning"